# jquery file not loading in edge in mvc application

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, model-view-controller, microsoft-edge

I have an MVC application which has a simple jQuery function to load a partial view, depending upon input parameters.  When I start the application in Chrome, or start the application using Edge and browse to my localhost in chrome everything works fine.  If I browse the application in Edge either as the starting browser in visual studio or browse to it by starting the application in Chrome, Edge does not load the jQuery files and ignores the function.  I have a another similar application in the same drive as this one where I do not have that problem.  I'm guessing I turned something off inadvertently, but I can't find or figure out what.  I'm using VS 2017.

This is the jQuery function:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){


    var frm1 = $('#searchform');

    frm1.submit( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: frm1.attr('method'),
                url: frm1.attr('action'),
                data: frm1.serialize(),
                success: function (data) { $('#results').html(data) }
            });
         })
}  ); // End document ready

})(this.jQuery);
```

These are the relevant bundles:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/custom.js"));  
\\custom.js contains the above function

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));}
```

my layout pages

```
    <html>
<headers and css loads/>
 <body>
     <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on my side, I have created a sample using your code, it seems that everything works well on my side. Please try to restart the VS and retest your application. And you should also make sure that you are using the Layout page. Besides, you can also use F12 developer tools to check the detailed error message.

Comment: I also can't duplicate it on a new solution.  F12 shows me that the js scripts are not loading.  They don't even show up as an error, they don't appear in the network tab.  Is there some setting that tells edge not to load script files?

Comment: You can create a new application  and run it in the Edge browser, check whether the  issue is related to the Edge browser setting (disable the JavaScript). If you want to disable JavaScript, you could refer to [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/955596/how-do-i-disable-javascript-in-microsoft-edge) to change the Group Policy settings.